# After adding dependency in pom.xml com.google.firebase still not recognized

Tags: firebase, maven

I am trying to add Firebase to my project, but after adding some dependencies in the maven pom.xml I still get errors from importing firebase classes (I use VS Code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.socgaming</groupId>
  <artifactId>socialBall</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>socialBall</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
   <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>google</id>
        <name>Google</name>
        <url>https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2</url>
    </repository>
   </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

I tried different approaches but nothing worked. Where am I wrong ? Thank you for the Help. Here is how my project is structured as well

[image]

```
C:\Users\Kostadinov\Desktop\Training\project\socgam21_group10\server\socialBall>mvn verify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.socgaming:socialBall >----------------------
[INFO] Building socialBall 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ socialBall ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Kostadinov\Desktop\Training\project\socgam21_group10\server\socialBall\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ socialBall ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Kostadinov\Desktop\Training\project\socgam21_group10\server\socialBall\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ socialBall ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Kostadinov\Desktop\Training\project\socgam21_group10\server\socialBall\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ socialBall ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ socialBall ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ socialBall ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Kostadinov\Desktop\Training\project\socgam21_group10\server\socialBall\target\socialBall-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.961 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-19T22:55:46+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Does your project compile without any issue on plain command line?

Comment: yes, i edited it and posted what i receive

Comment: I also tried adding google repository and android maven plugin as I sow that in one question I saw in stackoverflow but that didn't help me

Comment: Based on trying to access https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2 which does not work could be the problem..?